# offline-firebase does not work EmberFire (and ember-cli)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, offlineapps, emberfire

When I try to use offline-firebase with EmberFire, I get these errors (and nothing gets saved to firebase):

[image: offline-firebase errors]

`adapters/application.js`

```
export default DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend({  
  firebase: new OfflineFirebase('https://woot.firebaseio.com/quiz').on('value', function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot);
  }, undefined, undefined, true)
});
```

`app.js`

```
OfflineFirebase.restore();
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase-debug.js"></script>
<script src="js/OfflineFirebase.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/woot-prototype.js"></script>
```

`controllers/index.js`

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    init: function() {
        this.set('user', Ember.Object.create());
    },
    actions: {
        getUser: function(){
            var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
                email: this.get('user.email'),
                name: this.get('user.name')
            });
            console.log(newUser);
            newUser.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Is this offline-firebase problem or I am doing something wrong? :)
https://github.com/yeldarby/offline-firebase/issues/6

Comment: Pleas include the error text in your question. A link to a screenshot is not enough.